# Printing child processes given a pid (MINIX)

Tags: c, struct, operating-system, minix

I'm working on a project at the moment and as part of it I need to implement system calls/library functions in MINIX.

As part of this I need to be able to print a list of child processes of a given process, using its pid. I think I've found part of what I need, but I'm stuck with making it work with a given pid.

```
struct task_struct *task; 
struct list_head *list;

list_for_each(list, &current->children) { 
    task = list_entry(list, struct task_struct, children); 
}
```

Does this seem like something close to what I'd need? I know that for passing a pid for me to use I'd need to use:

```
struct task_struct find_task_by_pid(pid_t pid);
```

But combining this with the above isn't something I've done before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, doesn't seem too efficient to me but it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "pm.h"
#include "mproc.h"

int do_printchildpids(){
int i = m_in.m1_i1; //pid received 
int c = 0; //Counter


printf("Searching for children of process: %d \n", i);

while (c < NR_PROCS)
  {
    int n = mproc[c].mp_pid; //First process in the list of availableprocess
    int pinx = mproc[c].mp_parent; //Index of parent of the current process
    int ppid = mproc[pinx].mp_pid; //pid of parent process


    if(i == ppid) //If parents pid matches the given value
    {
    printf("%d \n", n); //Print the childs id
    c++;
    }
    else
    {
    c++;
    }
  }
return -1;
}
```